# Forward/backward algorithms for simple (non Hidden) Markov Chain

Tags: algorithm, markov-chains

Given an initial transition matrix

[image]

where x is the initial node from where a random walker is starting his walk.

We then can calculate the quantity :

[image]

which represents the expected number of times the edge (i, j), is visited while starting the walk in x given that the walk length is L.

Because the calculation of the above quantity is very time consuming due to some matrix powering like Q^(L-1) I was wondering if there are similar algorithms to the forward-backward algorithms for the HMMs in order to calculate that quantity for that simple (visible) Markov chain.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to compute powers Q. Doesn't it suffice to repeatedly multiply the current state distribution by Q?

Comment: I'm not sure If I got what you suggest. What do you mean bt the current state? Can you give an example?

Comment: The state distribution after k steps is x Q^k. I'm suggesting that, instead of computing Q^k and then multiplying by x, compute (x Q) Q ... k multiplications by Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some tricks with markov models for these kind of questions.

In your case I assume that you want the *expected number of times a specific edge i,j is visited* given

1. transition probability matrix *P*,
2. all chains start in *x*, and
3. all chains have length *L*

I will ignore any special form like yours of P which might improve speed further. The general idea (that can be extended to other questions about the markov system) is this:

First we realize that if we would know the actual number of visits to the state from which the edge starts, we can use the transition matrix *P* to infer that actual counts of a specific edge.

Example: Say in chains of length 50 we know that 10 times we are in state 1 in average. And in P the chance to jump from 1 -> 2 is 50%. Then in chains of length 50 + 1 we find that 10 * 50% = 5 of all edges on average are 1 -> 2. (Note the difference between state visits and edge visits!)

Luckily, the expectation to be in a state can be written in form of a geometric series of the transition matrix. You can use the usual trick for a geometric series as long as the denominator can be inverted which is unfortunately not the case for a transition matrix. At least not trivially, but this can be solved.

Let me write the number of state visits vector using LaTeX

```
E_c{x_0,L} = \sum_{i=0}^{L-1} P^i x_0 = (\sum_{i=0}^{L-1} P^i) x_0
```

where x_0 is vector giving the initial distribution in your case zero everywhere, but one state of your choice.

Note that the sum before the x_0 is a matrix that contains all state counts for all possible initial states. Now to compute this matrix. Using the geometric series we get

```
\sum_{i=0}^{L-1} P^i = \frac{P^L - Id}{P - Id}
```

with Id the identity matrix. The denominator is singular so we have a problem. Luckily the numerator has *the same problem* so we can fix this. Use an eigenvalue decomposition and rewrite P using matrices of left and right eigenvectors and a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues evD

```
P = evR evD evL

\sum_{i=0}^{L-1} P^i = \sum_{i=0}^{L-1} (evR evD evL)^i 
                     = evR (\sum_{i=0}^{L-1} evD^i ) evL
```

Now we are left with simple geometric series for each eigenvalue. One eigenvalue is 1 and this one causes problems. But in this case we just sum up. From 0 to L-1 summing 1 is just L. The other geometric series are well-defined.

Pro: You can now compute the edges for any choice of x_0 or L in an instant.

Con: You always have to do the eigendecomposition which is a problem if you have large matrices, though.

Example:

A simple even symmetric matrix

```
P = {{0.8,   0.15, 0.05}, 
     {0.075, 0.85, 0.075}, 
     {0.05,  0.15, 0.8}}
```

we chose `L = 51` (50 transitions) and `x_0 = {1, 0, 0}`

```
evD = {{1., 0., 0.}, {0., 0.75, 0.}, {0., 0., 0.7}}
evR = {{-0.612372, -0.707107, 0.612372}, {-0.612372, 0, -0.612372}, {-0.612372, 0.707107, 0.612372}}
evL = {{-0.408248, -0.816497, -0.408248}, {-0.707107, 0, 0.707107}, {0.408248, -0.816497, 0.408248}}

GeometricSeries(evD,50) = {{50., 0., 0.}, {0., 4., 0.}, {0., 0., 3.33333}}

E_c(x_0 = 1) = evR GeometricSeries(evD,50) evL {1, 0, 0}
             = {15.3333, 11.6667, 11.3333}
```

For transition 1 -> 2 (15%) we get 15.3333 * 15% = 2.3